# Authenticating routes with Jwt Token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

```
const userModel = require('../models/UsersModel')
const express = require('express')
const routes = express.Router()
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config()





routes.post('/signup', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt()
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)
        const newUser = new userModel({username: req.body.username, password: hashedPassword})
        await newUser.save()
        res.status(201).send(newUser)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
    }
})
routes.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await userModel.find({"username": req.body.username})
    console.log(user)
    if (user == null) {
        return res.status(400).json({"status": false, "message": "Invalid username and password"})
    }
    try {
       if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password)) {
           const accessToken = jwt.sign(req.body.username, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
           res.status(200).json({"status": true, "message": "Login successful", accessToken: accessToken})
       } else {
           res.send('Not Allowed')
       }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
    }
})



module.exports = routes
```

How would I authenticate my employee routes using the json token thats generated in user routes login? Having trouble getting it to work? In the second code snippet I have to only allow users that have been authenticated and have recieved a token.

```
const employeeModel = require('../models/EmployeesModel')
const express = require('express')
const routes = express.Router()
const userRoutes = require('./UserRoutes')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config()


routes.post('/employees', async(req, res) => {
    const newEmployee = new employeeModel(req.body)
    try{
        await newEmployee.save()
        res.status(201).send(newEmployee)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({message: err.message})
    }

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use middleware for this:

Create middleware file say check-auth.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") return next();

  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

    if (!token)
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Authentication Failed!" });

    const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
    req.userData = decodedData;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Authentication Failed!" });
  }
};
```

In your routes file:

```
const checkAuth = require("path of middleware file");
const employeeModel = require('../models/EmployeesModel')
const express = require('express')
const routes = express.Router()
const userRoutes = require('./UserRoutes')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config()

routes.post('/employees',checkAuth, async(req, res) => {
    const newEmployee = new employeeModel(req.body)
    try{
        await newEmployee.save()
        res.status(201).send(newEmployee)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({message: err.message})
    }

});
```